# IIS 7 URL Rewrite difficulties

Tags: iis, iis-7, redirect, url-rewriting

To configure an IIS rewrite rule to redirect traffic to my site to a different URL.

Basically I am trying to redirect this url: www.sharepointalex.co.uk to www.sharepointalex.co.uk/blog. At the moment it is pointing at the root of my site (a wedding website I setup for my partner and I).

www.sharepointalex.co.uk is a domain pointer on WinHost.

The rule I have so far is:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Blog" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="www.sharepointalex.co.uk" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/blog" redirectType="Temporary" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.sharepointalex.co.uk" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

However this doesnt seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Where is this code? Are you working with ASP.NET and web.config, or strictly with IIS? If the latter, your question does not belong here.

Comment: With IIS - I'll try posting over at the WinHost forums and see if they have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The match URL should not include the host name.